# Where does the dtls domain args in webrtc come from?

Tags: ssl, webrtc, dtls

For webrtc peers, what domain is dtls used for negotiation? I am puzzled. There seems to be no relevant attribute definition in the sdp. Is it the domain where the web page is located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebRTC doesn't use a certificate authority. No domains are involved. With WebRTC the `Authenticity` that you get from PKI is just replaced with certificate fingerprints.

Each side generates a certificate and then shares the fingerprint in the Session Description (Offer/Answer). After the DTLS handshake is complete  it makes sure that the certificate exchanged was the same.

How DTLS actually works is explained in [WebRTC for the Curious#Securing](https://webrtcforthecurious.com/docs/04-securing/#dtls) a bit more.

Comment: but, openssl SslConnector needs a domain. In this case, what value should be passed in for this parameter?